# How do I refer to the values that were just inserted (in a TRIGGER statement)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

```
CREATE TRIGGER ATTENDANCE_INSERTION_TRIGGER
ON course_enrollment
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

--insert **what just was inserted in course_enrollment** into course_schedule_attendance

END
GO
```

How do I refer to  **what just was inserted in course_enrollment** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ATTENDANCE_INSERTION_TRIGGER 
ON course_enrollment 
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN

  --insert **what just was inserted in course_enrollment** into
  -- course_schedule_attendance  
  INSERT course_schedule_attendance  
      (course_id, student_id)
    SELECT
      course_id, student_id --you could use: INSERTED.course, INSERTED.student_id
      FROM INSERTED
END 
GO
```

you could also do this in a single INSERT, without the trigger:

```
--insert a single row in both tables at one time
INSERT course_enrollment 
      (course_id, student_id)
      OUTPUT course_id, student_id INTO course_schedule_attendance  
   VALUES (@xyz, @abc)

--or insert a set of rows into both at one time
INSERT course_enrollment 
      (course_id, student_id)
      OUTPUT course_id, student_id INTO course_schedule_attendance  
   SELECT
       xyz, abc
       FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values from the inserted table

```
SELECT * FROM INSERTED I
```

So for example if course_enrollment had a field called course_id and student_id, to get those fields you can do a

```
SELECT I.course_id,I.student_id FROM INSERTED I -- I is just an alias and is not needed but it helps
```

Comment: But how do you refer to the individual column values from what was inserted?

Comment: INSERTED will have the exact same structure as the course_enrollment table

Comment: Suppose course_enrollment has (course_id, student_id), do I refer to the individual column values as INSERTED.student_id?  Thx for your help btw

Comment: That should work IF you don't alias the INSERTED Table with a, have a look I've updated my code

Answer (score 0):

There are two useful trigger meta-tables, both of which match the schema of the table that the trigger is on, INSERTED and DELETED.

Interestingly if you run an update statement, the trigger meta tables will be have rows in both INSERTED and DELETED, the DELETED rows corresponding to "before the update" and INSERTED with "after the update".

This also makes it useful for audit purposes.